# Add a loading indicator or spinner for rendering delay (Not for subscription ready)

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

My meteor app template is taking a 1 second delay between creation and rendering. The delay is after the data subscription is available, so it seems that the 1 second is the time required by Blaze to read the data locally and draw all the objects in DOM (Perhaps most of them are in cache).

The question is: There is a way to add a spinner in the loaded template to cover the delay between myTemplate.OnCreated and myTemplate.onRendered?

Thanks in advance.
[image: 0.5 sec delay in Blaze._materializeDOM]

Comment: I am not familiar with meteor (however, I've heard good things).  Is there a way to add a class to an element depending on some state?  If so, then you can add a spinner.

Comment: Yes.  Perhaps I should add the element with that class to all other templates in my app, since the user can go to my heavy template from anywhere.  It would be better to show the spinner only in the template in process of rendering.

Comment: I would first determine exactly where the delay comes from. When you say "data subscription is available", do you mean you subscribed, or the `onReady` callback was triggered?

Comment: Exactly.  The delay is merely by blaze rendering, after the subscription is ready.

Comment: This is way too long. Unless you have the world's most complicated set of Blaze templates there's no way it would take a whole second to render short of it being chock full of images that need to download. You should *profile* your application when rendering this template to see where it spending the time.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I did, but maybe I could be misunderstanding the timeline (I have attached it to the question).   As I can see half second is used for blaze rendering (of only 18 contact items on my app.  When the contact list go beyond the delay is almost 1 second).  All of this is counted after subscription is available.

Perhaps you may have a point since hidding and showing the items in DOM don't take too long to render.

Comment: Can you post your Template code for us to look at?

Comment: `<template name="eventContainer">
{{#if subsReady}}  // check Subscription availability
 {{#if isReady}}   // check Template onRendered completed
  {{#if peersUIUnidos}}
   {{> containerUnidos}}
  {{else}}
   {{> containerSeparados}}
  {{/if}}
 {{else}}
  {{> loading}}
 {{/if}}   
{{else}}
 {{> loading}}
{{/if}}
</template>`

Comment: Sorry if It doesn't look good here but just to show you the implementation of your suggestion.  The eventContainer -> onCreated onRendered and helper are exactly as you suggest.

Comment: @Ruben can you edit your question and include your Template js code (not the HTML). I need to see exactly what you are doing to help.

Comment: @jordanwillis Sure.  I already did.

Comment: I don't see any issues based upon the code you posted (but its hard to tell without seeing your subTemplate or publication code).  One piece of feedback is that your `onCreated` logic doesn't make sense.  You don't need to check the status of Meteor as you are doing. In fact, I cannot think of a compelling case where you would need to check if the connection is active. Regardless, your initiating the same subscription even if the page is not connected to Meteor (so why check?).  At this point all I can recommend is to send a github link to your project and I can look at the whole project.

Comment: The onCreated logic allows the app offline use.  If I wait for the subscription response to render and the server is not available, the spinner will spin forever.  If the server is not connected I just show the data in local collection turning off the spinner.   But you are right, the Meteor.subscribe line when there is no connection might not be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very similar in logic to @jordanwillis solution, just was needed to add a timeout on template created:

```
<template name="contactList">
   {{#if contactListRendered }}
      <!-- Here show the contact list -->
   {{else}}
      <!-- show loading indicator or spinner  -->
   {{/if}}
</template>
```

Logic:

```
Template.contactList.onCreated( function() {
   Session.set("contactListRendered", false);
});

Template.contactList.onRendered( function() {
   setTimeout(function(){Session.set("contactListRendered", true);}, 1);
});

Template.contactList.helpers({
   contactListRendered: function() {
   return Session.get("contactListRendered");
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you are after and its a little difficult to pick the right one for your case without seeing more of your code.

But if you are not performing any specific logic in your template definition once your subscription is ready then you can use the Blaze [`Template.subscriptionsReady`](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) helper.

```
<template name="notifications">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    <!-- put your view code here -->
  {{else}}
    <!-- put loading indicator here -->
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

If you are doing something special to your data once your subscription is ready, or if you need to wait until all the data is fully loaded then you can control when the Template renders using a `ReactiveVar`.

Template definition:

```
<template name="notifications">
  {{#if isReady }}
    <!-- put your view code here -->
  {{else}}
    <!-- put loading indicator here -->
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Template logic:

```
Template.notifications.onCreated(function() {
  this.isReady = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.notifications.onRendered(function() {
  this.subscribe('activeNotifications', () => {
    this.isReady.set(true);
  });
});

Template.notifications.helpers({
  isReady: function() {
    return Template.instance().isReady.get();
  },
});
```

I usually implement my loading indicator logic in its own Template so that I can re-use it across the site.

Comment: The `activeNotifications` was just an example for demonstrating the concept.  You would replace this with your specific subscription (if you are dealing with one).  It would be easier if you posted your Template code then I can respond specifically.

Comment: I don't have any activeNotifications collection (line 6) to subscribe.  I tried what you suggested without that line but the spinner never is shown maybe since it is inside notifications template and will only render when notifications renders completely, and when it happens the isReady is already true.

Comment: It's working now!  Adding a setTimeout of 1 millisecond when changing the variable value, did the job.  Thanks!